# Java serialized bean to xml

Tags: java, xml, converters

How can i convert a Java Bean in a simple XML. I need a standard methed for alla object.

For example:

```
public Class Customers {
    public Class Person {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public String setName(newName) {
            this.name = newName;
        }
    } //end Person class

    public String getPerson() {
         return this.Person;
    }
    public String setName(newPerson) {
        this.Person = newPerson;
    }
} //end Customers class
```

Instantiate by:

```
Customers customers = new Customers();
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Siegfried");
customers.setPerson(person);

System.out.print(beanToXml(customers));
```

Xml Output:

```
<Customers>
    <Person>
        <name>Siegfried</name>
    </Person>
</Customers>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use JAXB for this, this is the perfect use case, all you need to do is annotate your bean.

Example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

Comment: I work in a old project, I can't insert jaxb annotation in all bean.

Comment: I have 1-200 beans. Change all beans takes a lot of time.

Comment: @Spirit - You can use JAXB (included in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6) without any annotations:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party like `XStream`.It allows to save object to , and it does not need that object must be `Serializable`. We had similair problem in our company (class that cannot be modified and must be saved) and `XStream` helped us. Please look at: http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html for simple tutorial.